# Google Sheets: Find All Instances of a Substring and Return Indices of Cells

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Here's the thing I want to do:
For every cell in `A2:A`, find all instances where the string is a substring of a cell in `B2:B`, and return all the cell indices (offsetted by a column) concatenated into a single string.

I'm currently using `=TEXTJOIN(",",true,IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(SEARCH(A2,B$2:B))))` which gives me the first occurrences within the text. I also know how to use the `OFFSET` function. How do I get the cell indices instead?
[picture of sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3EjQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,FILTER(B:B,REGEXMATCH(C:C,B2)))

FILTER(B:B,REGEXMATCH(C:C,B2) - Filter out all rows in B column if the corresponding row in C column has the specified string (e.g. AA).